# WMS GetFeatureInfo request returns nothing with GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm having trouble with a select feature example in GeoServer and OpenLayers. For some reason the request returns nothing.

Here's the stripped down version that produces this:

I have a small WMS layer(~100 parcels) with polygons, and address data that I am overlaying Google Maps with a projection. It displays correctly.

```
map = map(...); //standard map creation
gmap = ...; // standard street map creation
wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Parcels",
            "http://192.168.0.205/geoserver/wms", 
            {'layers': 'test:parcel', 'format':'image/png', 'transparent':'true'},
            {'opacity': 0.5, 'isBaseLayer': false, 'visibility' : false, 'zoomMin' : 15}
);
```

Then I create the click control...

```
infoControls = 
           {
            click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo
            ({
                url: 'http://192.168.0.205/geoserver/wms', 
                title: 'Get parcel data',
                layers: [wmslayer],
                queryVisible: true
            })
        };
```

Added the layers, add the control and activate it

```
map.addLayers([gmap, wmslayer]);  
infoControls[0].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
map.addControl(infoControls[0]);
infoControls.click.activate();

//show info callback
function showInfo(evt) {    
    console.log(evt);
    alert(evt.text);
}
```

But when I click on the map inside I parcel, it gives the alert is blank, and so is the features in Firebug (from console.log(evt)).

The GET request in Firebug is red.

```
BBOX    -10845148.716676,5165071.048543,-10843335.725912,5166002.624825
FEATURE_COUNT   10
FORMAT  image/png
HEIGHT  390
INFO_FORMAT text/html
LAYERS  test:parcel
QUERY_LAYERS    test:parcel
REQUEST GetFeatureInfo
SERVICE WMS
SRS EPSG:900913
STYLES  
VERSION 1.1.1
WIDTH   759
X   582
Y   246
```

Edit: The database is CRS is EPSG:4327 and projecting it to Google Mercator... Do I need to project the BBOX of the request back to EPSG:4327 before I send the WMS request? How can I do this?

Here is the GeoServer log of the request

```
2011-07-22 14:49:01,301 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getFeatureInfo
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.1.1
 output format: image/png
 width height: 759,390
 bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[-1.0845637448332E7 : -1.0842011466804E7, 5164278.964868 : 5166142.117432]
 layers: test:parcel
 styles: polygon
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@a837896f]
    XPixel = 385
    YPixel = 144
    FeatureCount = 10
    InfoFormat = text/html
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    Version = 1.1.1
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://192.168.0.205:8080/geoserver/
    Get = false
    RawKvp = {INFO_FORMAT=text/html, BBOX=-10845637.448332,5164278.964868,-10842011.466804,5166142.117432, QUERY_LAYERS=test:parcel, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=390, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, STYLES=, WIDTH=759, FEATURE_COUNT=10, VERSION=1.1.1, FORMAT=image/png, LAYERS=test:parcel, Y=144, X=385, SRS=EPSG:900913}
    RequestCharset = null
```

Comment: You made sure WMS is enabled on your geoserver?

Comment: Can you post firebugs response? or is it not present?

Comment: @capdragon Hello! Yes WMS is enabled. The response section is blank.

Comment: is the page served from the same address as your geoserver? if not you'll need a proxy

Comment: @iant Oooh... I've been using an Apache server on my machine for testing. So I put on on the same machine, but the addresses are different (different ports 80 vs 8080) and it still wont work. Why does it work for the layer image and not feature info? How would I set up the proxy- Is this just configuring the HTTPD server?

Comment: if the ports are different then you need a proxy or to relay the tomcat/geoserver through apache see http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/software/java.html

Comment: It works for images because images hardly ever do something scary to our machine while actual code can be bad.

Comment: Have you tried opening the getfeatureinfo link in firebug in another window or tab and sees what it returns?

Comment: @sophia Cool I opened it in a new tab and got the feature data what I was looking for... So that means there must be something wrong with my WMSGetFeature control?

Comment: @nate - if you manually paste in the URL and it returns the correct data then it is the issue iant describes. You can get data from other sites, but JavaScript is not allowed to.

Comment: @iant Thank you. It took a while because this is all new and I'm not much of a sys admin. I was trying to figure out how to configure Jetty but realized I didn't have to. Anyway, post it as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So mostly for future readers of this question - when you are doing getFeatureInfo requests to a *different* server (which includes a difference in the *port* number) you need a proxy - see http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost for more discussion.

Comment: I have the same issue with openlayers 3. Pl see this question ... -> http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172591/sld-applying-not-working-in-open-layers-3