# WMSGetFeatureInfo not finding my layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

Having a problem trying to get WMSGetFeatureInfo to work in openlayers - running off of Geoserver (http://gisnexus.com/cmha/cmha_site_test.html) you click on any feature, it shows as if the layer is being read from opengeospatial.net - but nowhere in the code does it call out to it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WMS Request Returns nothing with Geoserver](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12535/wms-request-returns-nothing-with-geoserver)

Comment: I just went to your site, clicked a feature, and got a GetFeatureInfo response from gisnexus.com - what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

WMSGetFeatureInfo is to retrieve information from a WMS server.
(http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html)

I you want WFS information you need to use GetFrature control: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/GetFeature-js.html

Check you are using the right control.